# Figuring line of code with source script both inline and external

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In Javascript from browser, is there a programmatic way to find out the source of the script with the current line number in a similar way `console.log` displays in  Developer console.

Comment: Yes, _sort of_. Depending on how reliable you want it to be. Is this debug-related or does it need to be more robust?

Comment: I am working on a plugin for Chrome that tracks properties on a Object similar to Object.watch in firefox. I am looking to point to the source script with the line number that changed the property value.

Comment: Ugh, OK then. In that case, it sounds serious. Basically, what you want to do in either case is get a hold of the stacktrace and then work from there. The "tricky" part is that you cannot _officially_ get a stack trace. What you could do is use `new Error().stack` which will give you a string which you can then parse but it's non-standard (works in Chrome and other browsers, though) and it's not a really good solution for the long run. There are some stacktrace libraries I've seen - maybe you can try those and see if they do something better.